# python convert a string to an xls document for processing

Tags: python-2.7, xls

```
new_list = eval(my_list[0])  # my_list contains dictionaries

def get_next_file():
    for key, value in new_list.iteritems():
        yield value

file = get_next_file
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=file)
for sheet in book.sheet_names():
    print sheet
```

I am trying to take a string from a dict and turn it into an xls file so it can be processed. It was an xls file that I used str(list(xls_file)) so that it could be saved in my database.

Any thoughts?

the saved string prints out as hex with some words in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library **xlrd** you are using is only to read informations from an excel file.
If you want to write a new excel file you need to use **xlwt**.
If you want to change some cells in an excel file you should use **xlutils**.
Homepage of these three libraries: http://www.python-excel.org/